# How to make my submenu return to Main Menu

Tags: java, arraylist, menu

I've been looking throughout the forum and I haven't found a solution.

I have the main Switch menu in the Main class to perform a simple calculation, it calls the submenu in another class to make the calc and add the value inside an array.
Once the calc is done I want to go back to the main menu and select option 2 that shows the Array, I create a new instance of the main class and it works, however, gets my array empty.

How can I fix it?

```
public class MainMenu {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MainMenu menu = new MainMenu();

        menu.Menu();

    }

    public void Menu() {

        Submenu submenu = new Submenu();

        int option;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("1 - Calc. 2- Exit");
        option = scanner.nextInt();

        switch (option) {

        case 1:
            System.out.println("Option 1");
            submenu.Calc();
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Show Array");
            System.out.println(submenu.toString());
            break;

        }

    }

}
```

**Submenu Class:**

```
public class Submenu {

    MainMenu menu = new MainMenu();
    ArrayList<Integer> arrayTest = new ArrayList<>();

    private int sum;

    public void Calc() {
        sum = 5 + 5;
        arrayTest.add(sum);
        menu.Menu();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Array Test: " + arrayTest;
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean, empty array?

Comment: The `MainMenu` object in your `Submenu` is not the same as the `MainMenu` object from the `main` method.

Comment: also, don't use the name of your class as name for a method.

Comment: You can pass the instance of Menu to the constructor of SubMenu and use that

Comment: Here`s my array empty once it gets back to the MainMenu.

1 - Calc. 2- Show Array
1
Option 1
Sum: 10
1 - Calc. 2- Show Array
2
Show Array
 []

Comment: have you read the previous comments?

Comment: Sorry now I did, would you mind writing how to do it?

Comment: don't create an instance of Menu in the SubMenu class, you need to re-use the one you already have, so pass that to the constructor of SubMenu

Comment: Ok, I did it but now I got an infinity loop

Answer (score 0):

I did some changes trying to solve it. I have my MainMenu class passing the instance to my Submenu in another class. However, I got an infinity loop, any suggestion?

public class MainMenu {

```
private int option;

Submenu submenu = new Submenu(new MainMenu());

public void Menu() {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("1 - Calc. 2- Show Array");
    option = scanner.nextInt();

    switch (option) {

    case 1:
        System.out.println("Option 1");
        submenu.Calc();
        break;

    case 2:
        System.out.println("Show Array");
        break;

    }

}
```

}

public class Submenu {

```
private int sum;
MainMenu a;

ArrayList<Integer> arrayTest = new ArrayList<>();

public Submenu(MainMenu object) {
    this.a = object;
}



public void Calc() {
    sum = 5 + 5;
    System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
    a.Menu();

}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Array Test: " + arrayTest;
}
```

}